# Pathfinder DR and ability damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In Pathfinder does [Damage Reduction](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#damage-reduction) (e.g. the barbarians DR 2/- for e.g.) reduce the ability damage from, say, a [Greater Shadow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/shadow.html) (1d8 Strength)?

Answer (score 11):

**Sometimes**, but **not in the example**.

In [Damage reduction](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#damage-reduction) it states:

> Whenever damage reduction completely negates the damage from an attack, it also negates most special effects that accompany the attack, such as injury poison, a monk's stunning, and injury-based disease. **Damage reduction does not negate touch attacks, energy damage dealt along with an attack, or energy drains.** Nor does it affect poisons or diseases delivered by inhalation, ingestion, or contact.

(My emphasis)

A [Greater Shadow](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/shadow.html)'s (The shadow?) attack is:

> Melee incorporeal touch +11 (1d8 Strength)

This is a touch attack, so DR will not stop this, doubly so as there is no damage to stop/negate thus the entire attack is str loss, not damage.

**Other situations**

For other attacks it will depend on how the ability damage is delivered.

- If the attack is a **non-touch** attack and deals **damage** to the target and also drains ability damage through (say) poison or disease **then** if the DR stops **all** the damage the poison and therefore ability drain is stopped.
- If the attack is a non-damaging **touch** type attack (Such as the Shadow) then the ability damage **isn't** negated, the DR has no effect. Note this would also include spells such as [Touch of Idiocy](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/touchOfIdiocy.html#_touch-of-idiocy) - DR is no protection against this.

See also [This related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/several-damage-reduction-clarifications-for-pathfinder) regarding Damage reduction.

Comment: This answer focuses too much on the fact that the example given is a touch attack. The question specifically wondered about ability damage, which this answer barely touches on.

Comment: Good point; tidied it up to clarify for generic situations.

Comment: Ah, where are you getting the idea that touch attacks aren't subject to DR? It has nothing to do with if it's a touch attack or not; damage reduction only reduces slashing, piercing, and/or bludgeoning damage and never reduces energy damage, force damage, negative energy damage, ability damage, etc.

Comment: @Lord_Gareth The point being that if for example a sword does 2 damage + 1d8 Strength to a character with 3/-, the 1d8 Strength is negated by the DR.