# How can a creature using a weapon bypass DR X/—?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage-reduction

How can a creature using a weapon overcome a foe's [damage reduction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction) X/— (like that of the [barbarian](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm#damageReduction))? Are the only ways the martial maneuvers foehammer (*ToB* 59) and mountain hammer (*ToB* 84) *et al.*?

Comment: Just fair warning, this question might get closed. It’s a pretty broad topic. I’m personally not voting to close, as off the top of my head I can’t think of any physical attacks beyond the *foehammer* and *mountain hammer* you already have that fit the bill, which implies a complete list wouldn’t be too long, but often requests for comprehensive lists like this are considered too broad for the site.

Comment: I took a crack at editing this to stave off closure. The edit should open it up to a wider variety of answers if any exist. You can learn more about the quirks of damage reduction [here.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36745/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't, directly. However, elemental damage bypasses DR, and weapons can deal elemental damage by being enchanted, through some spells (including oils, like oil of flame arrow), and some alchemical items (like bladefire from Arms and Equipment).

The creature could also deal damage by dealing more damage than X, or with suffocation/drowning/etc.