# Damage reduction vs Dying/Bleeding Out

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-death, damage-reduction

When a character has less than 0 but more than -10 HP, they are considred "dying". According to the SRD:

> A dying character loses 1 hit point every round. This continues until the character dies or becomes stable.

However, a character or creature with damage reduction takes an x-amount less from any source of physical damage, which arguably includes the above.
Obviously (to me), having damage reduction doesn't automatically mean you're immune to bleeding out. However, is there any official source that explains this? If so, what does that source have to say about the matter?

Comment: [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36745/8610) asks about DR reducing damage from traps; [the accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36754/8610) (which is mine, by the way) details how and why DR only reduces damage from attacks. Is further explanation necessary?

Comment: I think not. All seems clear. I still think that, for the sake of anyone in the future asking this question, it might be helpful to give a similar or even the same answer here for ease of finding. But that's debatable.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you found that exchange useful. I hesitate to repost my answer, though, if only because I feel like it's double-dipping. Would it be okay were I to mark this as a duplicate? This question already does have an answer there, after all. Alternatively, now that you've learned the answer to your question, you could just answer it yourself.

Comment: Yes. Marking this as a duplicate is more than okay. Or, I can indeed just answer it. But that will come down to mostly a copy-paste either way.

Comment: I'll go ahead and close it. If a moderator overrules me (or, I guess, us?) let's hope users let it stand long enough to give you a shot at answering it first.