# In Pathfinder, do magical weapons automatically overcome damage reduction?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, damage-reduction

Let's say I have a monster with DR 10/Adamantine.

Would it be correct to say that if a PC attacks that monster with a +3 non-Adamantine weapon, the monster's DR would **not** be overcome?

The general question here is whether magical weapons automatically overcome damage reduction. My read is that magical weapons *can* overcome DR, but it's not guaranteed. Is that correct?

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate, but I'd suggest looking at http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/several-damage-reduction-clarifications-for-pathfinder for more about DR in Pathfinder.

Comment: I did see that question but I wanted to verify this particular scenario.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Correct on both counts. See the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Overcoming-DR).

- +1 and greater weapons overcome DR that is vulnerable to magic
- +3 and greater weapons overcome DR as if made from cold iron and/or silver
- +4 and greater weapons overcome DR as if made from adamantine
- +5 weapons overcome DR as if aligned

Thus, a +3 weapon over comes DR that is vulnerable to magic, cold iron, or silver, but not adamantine (unless it was actually made from adamantine). It would need +4 to overcome DR/adamantine without being adamantine.

Comment: It's worth noting that no amount of bonus will allow a magic weapon to overcome damage reduction as if it dealt a different damage type; If a creature has DR 10/bludgeoning, for example, a +5 dagger is still not going to do more damage striking with the pommel as an improvised weapon than if used as the maker intended.