# How much do multiple weapon enchantments cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

If I were to enchant a composite longbow with two +1 enchantments, how much would it cost?

I have a masterwork longsword (315gp).
I want to add the magic enchantments Keen and Bane to it. Both of those enchantments are a +1 price of 2000gp each. Would it cost 4000gp to enchant the longsword or would it have the cost of a +2 enchantment of 8000gp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Special properties are priced as if you were increasing the enhancement bonus of the item by that amount. So a *+1 keen longbow* costs the same as a *+2 longbow* and a *+1 keen bane longbow* costs the same as *+3 longbow*. All magic weapons must have at least +1, so a *keen longbow* or *keen bane longbow* would be impossible. Enhancement bonus costs scale quadratically, \$bonus^2 \times 2\,000\text{ gp}\$. So +1 is \$2\,000\text{ gp}\$, +2 (or *+1 keen*) is  \$8\,000\text{ gp}\$, and +3 (or *+1 keen bane*) is \$18\,000\text{ gp}\$.

These rules are stated in the section on [magic weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons):

> Special abilities count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of the item, but do not modify attack or damage bonuses (except where specifically noted).

> A weapon with a special ability must also have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.

Comment: Since it has multiple enchantments on it, equaling the price of a +3, can it hit monsters that can only be hit/damaged with +3 enchantments, or that's just a cost thing, not a damage thing?

Comment: @JesseCohoon To my knowledge, there are no such monsters (DR pierced by specific amounts of enhancement bonus died in the 3.0 to 3.5 transition); what you may be thinking of is Pathfinder’s rule that allows higher enhancement bonuses to pierce DR normally vulnerable to certain materials and/or alignments. Assuming that is what you mean, then no, a *+1 keen bane* weapon would not pierce that. In general, it is just for calculating the cost.

Comment: KRyan is correct, only the actual enhancement bonus allows you to overcome additional DRs, not the 'effective' bonus used for special quality pricing calculations. To bypass DR/adamantine you need a +5 weapon.

Comment: @GreySage So it has to be a "+5 longbow" per say, not a "+3 keen bane longbow"?

Comment: Correct. The equivalency is only for price.

Comment: Related, we have a question about the details of the DR system in Pathfinder here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/several-damage-reduction-clarifications-for-pathfinder

Comment: Note that because a *bane* weapon does count as having a higher-than-usual enhancement bonus against certain creatures, it might actually count as being able to ignore the DR of those creatures as if it had a higher enhancement bonus... Maybe. The interaction of those two rules elements is open to debate.